# List one HTML paragraph <p> at a time effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, effect

Please forgive me for the question title - I found it hard to word what effect I would like to create. Also I apologise if this is a duplicate but I found it hard to search for similar questions!.

I was wondering if there's any way to create a text list effect, where text paragraphs (as in `<p>line of text</p>` are displayed one after the other with a 15 second break between the next line showing. So, for example, there could be three lines of text - the first line is visible as the user is on the webpage (but the other two lines aren't visible yet to the user), then the second line could be made visible after the user has been on the page for 15 seconds, then after another 15 seconds (30 seconds after the user accessed the webpage), the third line of text could be displayed.

An example of this would be:
Line 1: "Please wait while we handle your request..."
Line 2 (displays 15 seconds later): "This is taking longer than usual to process - please wait..."
Line 3 (displays 15 seconds after Line 2 displayed): "We seem to be having trouble - please click here to contact support".

Apologies if my description is confusing - although I respect this isn't the best example, what I would like (as an effect) could be related to command prompt - i.e. after a command is typed and the user hits enter, for every action that's completed, a line of text is displayed under the command, followed by another line of text (depending on the command of course).

Another basic example is this image: http://s3.postimg.org/r59deyk2b/example.gif
If you continue watching the animated image, you'll see Line 2 displays after a random number of seconds (not exactly 30 seconds in this example).

Thanks very much in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR, but ....

```
var messages = [
    "Please wait while we handle your request...",
    "This is taking longer than usual to process - please wait...",
    "We seem to be having trouble - please click here to contact support"
];

$.each(messages, function(index, message) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#wrapper').append(
            $('<p />', {text : message})
        )
    }, index * 15000);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m8fc8/)